# Indent entire section using only preamble

Tags: margins, titlesec

I heavily use `org-mode` in Emacs to create TODO lists with timekeeping, which has a handy export to LaTeX feature. The problem is that in order to get my exported LaTeX document to look right, I want to indent entire sections, essentially treating sections like lists. It's very easy to create a template to copy and paste into every new file, but not feasible to edit the text directly as this would interfere with `org-mode`s ease of use. Thus:

Is there a way to indent an entire section, using only the preamble?

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\newcommand{\clock}{CLOCK: number number number \\}

\titleformat{\section}{\bfseries{}}{\roman{section}}{3pt}{#1}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\bfseries{}}{\roman{subsection}}{3pt}{$\rightarrow$#1}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{2em}{0pt}{0pt}
\begin{document}


\section{First section}
\clock

\section{Second section}
\clock
\clock
\clock

\subsection{First subsection}
\clock
\clock

\subsection{Second subsection}
\clock

\subsection{Third subsection}
\clock

\end{document}
```

I want the text with the red arrow to be indented to the same level as the section.
[image: Minimum working example]

Comment: Use `\leftskip 3ex` to create a global 3ex indent.  Reset with `\leftskip 0pt`.

Comment: `titlesec` does something at the end of the heading which invalidates this; it indents the heading fine, just not the text afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To be done in the preamble, all things of "that type" will be affected throughout the document.  Based on your problem description, I interpreted it to mean that you would like all subsections to be indented.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\newcommand{\clock}{CLOCK: number number number \\}

\titleformat{\section}{\bfseries{}}{\roman{section}}{3pt}{#1}
\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{0pt}{0pt}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\bfseries{}}{\roman{subsection}}{3pt}{$\rightarrow$#1}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{2em}{0pt}{0pt}

\let\svsection\section
\let\svsubsection\subsection
\def\section{\leftskip 0ex\svsection}
\def\subsection{\leftskip 4.5ex\svsubsection}
\begin{document}


\section{First section}
\clock

\section{Second section}
\clock
\clock
\clock

\subsection{First subsection}
\clock
\clock

\subsection{Second subsection}
\clock

\subsection{Third subsection}
\clock

\section{Third Section}
\clock

\end{document}
```

[image]