# Setting margins for sections, subsections, and subsubsections

Tags: sectioning, margins, enumerate

I'm currently writing a solutions manual for a textbook, and since the textbook has sections, subsections, and subsubsections, I need to make my book with those as well. But when i use all three, they don't auto-indent, so the levels of hierarchy (which is quite important for this book, trust me) are all jumbled up. How can I make a document so that it looks like the following?

[image]

(This example was made from Word '16, but since my manual has a LOT of equations and whatnot, I really need LaTeX)

I have a few ideas as to how I can do this, but currently all have either failed or I was not skilled enough to compile as such.

1. \newgeometry : I need several different margins on one page, but this command puts ever margin into its own page, which is DEFINITELY NOT WHAT I WANT.
2. \def\changemargin : Since I use \section, this environment was "\renewcommand"-ed into the preamble, but this made my other "\begin~\end"s go haywire. It also puts enumerates, which ought to be in my (sub(sub))sections, back in the original margin geometry.
3. Textboxes : Seems like the best answer to my question, but I don't know how to stick it inside the preamble.

Comment: you could (and probably should) use lists not sections, they are designed to indent

Comment: And how can I do that? And also, are those lists added to the ToC? Because I really, REALLY need the ToC, its one of the reasons why I make the solutions manual.

Comment: well... lists don't go in the toc by default and sections don't indent by default, either way is fixable, there are examples on site eg https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154049/indent-entire-section-using-only-preamble