# Titlesec and Leftskip

Tags: horizontal-alignment, titlesec

This was actually my very first question about latex five years ago, and it went unanswered. I have come full circle now and I still couldn't figure this out, but at least now I new what keywords to search for.

Anyways, I wanted to create document wide indentation for sections and subsections and the like. I have found a very good answer (see link at bottom) but I wanted to ask about it. The output is exactly what I wanted, but I do not understand why re-defining the `\section` and `\subsection` command was necessary. Infact when I tried without it, and instead attempted to insert `\leftskip=1in` into my titlesec formatting it did not work, but I cannot figure out why.

This code snipped generates the output shown below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec} 
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor} 
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
%\titleformat{command}[shape]{format}{label}{sep}{before}[after]
\titleformat{\section}[block]{\scshape}{}{0in}{#1}[]
\titleformat{\subsection}[block]{\scshape}{}{0in}{#1}[]


%\titlespacing{command}{left spacing}{before spacing}{after spacing}[right]
\titlespacing\section{0in}{20pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}{20pt}
\titlespacing\subsection{1in}{20pt plus 0pt minus 0pt}{10pt}


\let\svsection\section
\let\svsubsection\subsection
\def\section{\leftskip 0ex\svsection}
\def\subsection{\leftskip 1in\svsubsection}


\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}


\section{A Test Section}
\lipsum[2]

\subsection{A Test Subsection}
\lipsum[3]

\subsection{A Test Subsection}
\lipsum[3]

\section{A Test Section}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Thanks to Steven B. Segletes for getting me this far.

[Indent entire section using only preamble](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/154049/indent-entire-section-using-only-preamble/154052#154052)